# Exponential inequality with small parameter

Tags: calculus

Is it true or false: $$1+e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon}\leq 1?$$ when $0\leq x\leq1$, $\alpha>0$ and $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. If so how do I show this.

Comment: No, $e^x$ is always positive.

Comment: Try $x=1$ and see that it immediately breaks. Also try $x=0$ it is still bigger than 1.

Answer (score 5):

False since
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R,\quad e^x>0$$